# How do you test if a value is matches one of a set of values?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

so in python you can test like

```py
if value in ('value1', 'value2', ...):
    ....
```

is there an equilvant in xslt?

```xml
<xsl:if test="@value in ('value1', 'value2')">
    ...
</xsl:if>
```

without having to use a long list of or statements `@value = 'value1' or @value = 'value2'`

Comment: Yes, there is an equivalent - even in XSLT 1.0. However, you need to provide a less abstract example. Where are the values coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sets like this which check if a value is part of a set:

```
<xsl:if test="@value = ('value1', 'value2')">
  Succeeds if @value is either "value1" or "value2"
</xsl:if>
```

An inferior alternative in XSLT-1.0 is using a separate check for every value like this:

```
<xsl:if test="@value = 'value1' or @value = 'value2'">
  Succeeds if @value is either "value1" or "value2"
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Set comparison is possible in XSLT 1.0 too.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thx. And I was so mistaken that this feature is XSLT-2.0 only :-/

Comment: It's a core feature of the XSLT language. The only advantage XSLT 2.0 has is the ease of creating a sequence vs. a node-set in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: But XSLT 1.0 only has sets of nodes, not sets of strings. For the first example to work you need the data model to support sequences of strings, and that comes only with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay As I said in a comment to the question, we don't know where these values come from. If they come from the input XML, then they may already be a node-set. If they need to be hard-coded in the stylesheet, they can just as easily be hard-coded as a node-set. And if - as I suspect - OP is using libxslt, they can simply convert a delimited string to a node-set using the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function.